# GetAddrInfo cannot resolve ipv6.google.com (but nslookup can)

Tags: winapi, sockets, dns, ipv6

i can trying to use [`GetAddrInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to resolve [`ipv6.google.com`](http://ipv6.google.com):

```
wsaError = getaddrinfo("ipv6.google.com", null, null, ref addrInfo);
```

The returned socket error code is `11001` (No such host is known).

> **Note**: The deprecated legacy function [`GetHostByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not support IPv6. It has been replaced with [`GetAddrInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The strange thing is that i can use `nslookup` and it can find the address just fine:

**Question**

```
SendRequest(), len 33
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        ipv6.google.com, type = A, class = IN
```

**Authoritative Answer**

```
Got answer (106 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        ipv6.google.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  ipv6.google.com
        type = CNAME, class = IN, dlen = 9
        canonical name = ipv6.l.google.com
        ttl = 21743 (6 hours 2 mins 23 secs)
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  l.google.com
        type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 38
        ttl = 30 (30 secs)
        primary name server = ns4.google.com
        responsible mail addr = dns-admin.google.com
        serial  = 1486713
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 1800 (30 mins)
        default TTL = 60 (1 min)
```

**Non-authoritative question**

```
SendRequest(), len 33
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        ipv6.google.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
```

**Non-authoritative answer**

```
Got answer (82 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 2,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        ipv6.google.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  ipv6.google.com
        type = CNAME, class = IN, dlen = 9
        canonical name = ipv6.l.google.com
        ttl = 21743 (6 hours 2 mins 23 secs)
    ->  ipv6.l.google.com
        type = AAAA, class = IN, dlen = 16
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2607:f8b0:4009:801::1012
        ttl = 270 (4 mins 30 secs)

------------
Name:    ipv6.l.google.com
Address:  2607:f8b0:4009:801::1012
Aliases:  ipv6.google.com
```

What can cause `nslookup` to be able to resolve an address when [`GetAddrInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) cannot? And what can i do differently with `GetAddrInfo` so it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `AF_INET6` in `pHints` parameter to work with IPV6 addresses. This seems to be working for me:

```
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

dwRetval = getaddrinfo("ipv6.google.com", NULL, &hints, &result);
// check your dwRetval here ...
```

Comment: The lets me resolve `ipv6.google.com`, but then `stackoverflow.com` doesn't resolve. i still need to solve the issue of how `nslookup` can manage it.

Comment: i figured out *how* `nslookup` accomplishes its task. It runs an `A` query, then separately does an `AAAA` lookup. So i *have* to call `getaddrinfo` twice, once for IPv6 then again for IPv4.

Comment: Try setting `hints.ai_family` to `AF_UNSPEC` to allow `getaddrinfo()` to query both IPv4 and IPv6 information at the same time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Setting family to AF_UNSPEC does not help. i thought maybe family should be a bit-flag (`AF_INET6 or AF_INET`); but it *isn't* a bitwise flag.

Comment: No, it is not a bitmask. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx) clearly states: "A value of AF_UNSPEC for ai_family indicates the caller will accept any protocol family. This value can be used to return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for the host name pointed to by the pNodeName parameter. On Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP, IPv6 addresses are returned only if IPv6 is installed on the local computer."

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, wasn't a problem with the code, but the operating system. The following command meant windows resolved the IPv6 addresses correctly instead of giving a WSANO_DATA error:

Netsh interface teredo set state enterpriseclient

Source:

http://netscantools.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/ipv6-teredo-problems-and-solutions-on.html