# GetAddrInfo (C++) on Windows not handling IPv6 correctly, returning error code 11004 for domains that resolve fine through other means

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, ipv6, getaddrinfo

**Note: I looked extensively at a similar (but not duplicate) question here: [GetAddrInfo cannot resolve ipv6.google.com (but nslookup can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767107/getaddrinfo-cannot-resolve-ipv6-google-com-but-nslookup-can). This question is 9 years old, the OP is not experiencing the exact same behavior as I am, and the already-accepted answer does not solve my problem—in fact, I am specifically following the advice of that answer to no avail in the sample code below, and I'm getting a different error than on that question. Furthermore, the likelihood that I would succeed in getting anyone to engage on a question that old by merely commenting on it is nil. It is not the same problem as the problem I am having today, so I am created a new, more-detailed question.**

I have a Windows 10 machine running Visual Studio 2017 and a Windows Server 2016 machine running Visual Studio 2019. Both of the machines have IPv4 and IPv6 addresses configured. On both machines, `nslookup.exe` returns the expected results for three different domains:

```
> nslookup www.google.com
...
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4002:80a::2004
          172.217.3.228
...
> nslookup ipv4.google.com
...
Addresses:  74.125.136.102
...
> nslookup ipv6.google.com
...
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4002:812::200e
...
```

Now I'm trying to write an example program that uses `GetAddrInfo` to lookup these same three domains:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.Lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
   WSADATA wsaData;
   int err( WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) );
   if (err != 0)
   {
       std::cout << "WSAStartup failed with error " << err << std::endl << std::flush;
       return 1;
   }

   struct addrinfo hints;
   memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
   hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // so that we get each IP address once, instead of once per socket type
   hints.ai_protocol = 0; // we don't care about the protocol
   hints.ai_canonname = NULL; // should be NULL for hints
   hints.ai_addr = NULL; // should be NULL for hints
   hints.ai_next = NULL; // should be NULL for hints
   hints.ai_flags = 0;

   hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // I vary this and the hostname below

   struct addrinfo* results;

   int error = getaddrinfo("ipv6.google.com", NULL, &hints, &results);
   if (error != 0)
   {
       std::ostringstream msg;
       std::cout << "Could not resolve hostname due to ";
       std::cout << "the following error in getaddrinfo: " << error << ": ";
       if (error == -11)
       {
           std::cout << "EAI_SYSTEM";
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << gai_strerrorA(error);
       }
       std::cout << std::endl << std::flush;
       return 1;
   }

   for (struct addrinfo* result = results; result != NULL; result = result->ai_next)
   {
       if (result->ai_family == AF_INET6)
       {
           char buffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
           std::string ipv6Str(
               inet_ntop(
                   AF_INET6,
                   &((struct sockaddr_in6*)result->ai_addr)->sin6_addr,
                   buffer,
                   sizeof(buffer)));
           std::cout << ipv6Str << std::endl << std::flush;
       }
       else
       {
           char buffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
           std::string ipv4Str(
               inet_ntop(
                   AF_INET,
                   &((struct sockaddr_in*)result->ai_addr)->sin_addr,
                   buffer,
                   sizeof(buffer)));
           std::cout << ipv4Str << std::endl << std::flush;
       }
   }

   freeaddrinfo(results);

   return 0;
}
```

For simplicity, I'm just changing the `hints.ai_family` and hard-coded hostname, then re-compiling and re-running (with Visual Studio). These are the results I get:

| Hostname | hints.ai_family | Result | Expected? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) | `AF_UNSPEC` | One IPv4 and one IPv6 address | ✅ |
| [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) | `AF_INET` | One IPv4 address only | ✅ |
| [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) | `AF_INET6` | Err 11004: Name valid, no data | ⛔️ |
| ipv4.google.com | `AF_UNSPEC` | One IPv4 address only | ✅ |
| ipv4.google.com | `AF_INET` | One IPv4 address only | ✅ |
| ipv4.google.com | `AF_INET6` | Err 11004: Name valid, no data | ✅ |
| ipv6.google.com | `AF_UNSPEC` | Err 11004: Name valid, no data | ⛔️ |
| ipv6.google.com | `AF_INET` | Err 11004: Name valid, no data | ✅ |
| ipv6.google.com | `AF_INET6` | Err 11004: Name valid, no data | ⛔️ |

I've hammered at this for a full day now and I can't get `getaddrinfo` to return the expected results. Why isn't this working? It appears that `nslookup.exe` using something other than `getaddrinfo` (perhaps a more low-level query of root and glue name servers), because it works fine there. Also note that this code (with different includes and without the WSA startup procedure) is working just fine in RedHat, CentOS, Ubuntu, and macOS High Sierra.

Some things I've tried other than varying the `ai_family`, all of which yield the same results as in the table below:

```
ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV
ai_flags = AI_ALL
ai_flags = AI_ALL | AI_NUMERICSERV
ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM
ai_socktype = 0
ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP
```

Also, it turns out that `ipv6.google.com` is actually a `CNAME` for `ipv6.l.google.com`, so I tried using that domain, instead, to no avail.

Comment: FWIW, compiling the above on Linux (after stripping away all Windows-specific stuff), I get successful IPv6 lookups, and the expetced results. There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Must be some Windows-specific confiuration issue.

Comment: Did you read and try the other answer to the older question?

Comment: Yes. My code above specifically incorporates the answer to the older question: Querying AF_INET separately from AF_INET6. It worked for the OP who posted the older question, it does not work for me (as shown in the table of results above).

Comment: No, i wrote "_the other answer_" to the older question, not the accepted answer. It changes the Windows configuration to make it work.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @NickWilliams did you find any solution to this problem?   Almost everything uses getaddrinfo, so if getaddrinfo is broken so are a lot of other apps.

Comment: It's been 18 months since I posted this question, so I don't remember exact details of how we got to the point of "this problem isn't bothering us anymore." Here are the two key things I remember: 1) On Windows, if you don't have a **world-routable** IPv6 address (several prefixes don't count), `getaddrinfo` won't return IPv6 addresses, even when you explicitly ask for them (a bug, IMO). 2) Our needs for this helper function changed slightly, so now we're always using `AF_UNSPEC` and using our unique requirements to determine whether to return the v4 or v6 addresses returned by `getaddrinfo`.